# How should CI/CD deploy to production environment - copy artifacts or git pull from the server?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, node.js

We have an internal CI/CD server running private GitLab. It has the source code of our NodeJS project. We would like to run CI/CD and have it deploys to our on-premises production server. (Let's assume we are using the `master` branch).

Here are two most common methods I found on the internet:

1. Run `git pull` on the production server, run whatever build tasks needed (`npm install`, minify, etc...), and restart the service
2. Build the source codes on CI/CD server, rsync the built artifacts to production server and restart

Surprisingly, most of the examples I found on the internet uses method 1. This method requires the production server to have public internet access which may not be possible for many cases.

My question: is method 1 really the best way to deploy a NodeJS application to a production server? If yes, what is the reason?

Comment: if the production server doesn't have internet access you can't rsync either. And if you use a physical media instead you can use either method ;)

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of bad examples on the Internet.  Doing a `git pull` to distribute code is fabulous for development, but prone to all sorts of issues in practice.  It should not be used for production deploys without careful consideration of the negative consequences.

- What happens when somebody checks out a different branch?  You'll be sad when you keep `git pull`ing and nothing new shows up.
- How do you verify that the machine is running the expected release?  You can get this from `git`, but it is easier with most artifact systems.
- How do you release to machines that are on an air-gapped network?  Simulating your `git` server on a private network will be a fun time for you.

I'm not sure what format `npm` uses for artifacts, but it is also probably a good idea to back them up off of the CI/CD server and use a dedicated set of machines for serving up the artifacts.  If you spin up 100 machines at once would your CI/CD server handle it or fall over?  Isolating the artifact serving will avoid your CI/CD server being swamped and useless until the deploy is over.

Comment: I think, `git pull` should happen from the prod branch. If there is a push to another branch, it should be non-entity for the CI. However, I agree that doing CI of the prod, without a human supervision, is maybe too brave (=risky). But it is imho okay for a demo/test system.

Answer (score 2):

There are some source control systems that bill themselves as artifact management platforms as well (for example Perforce/Helix) and they try to support the mode of work. But git is especially bad at that. You would have to do a lot of work to make git support both development of code and management of artifacts efficiently. I'd suggest to not do that and use a different system for each. JFrog Artifactory for example is a great tool for that. Delivering code in containers and using docker hub for artifact store is another excellent way to do it. Even a bunch of upload/download scripts against S3 are better than storing your artifacts in git, as you might actively slow down the developer experience if you don't setup your solution exactly right.